# CEOs can't sell stock without risking imprisonment?

Tags: corporate-law, finance, securities, insider-trading

From what I understand if a CEO sells stock in their company and the stock price then goes down significantly within less than a year, they can get indicted for "insider trading" and face 5 to 10 years in jail.

Does this basically mean that a CEO basically has to hold onto stock indefinitely and only sell when they are sure the company is not facing a decline? So, basically sell and pray the company does not tank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insiders, such as a CEO, are allowed set up predetermined trading plans to [avoid accusations of insider trading](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rule-10b5-1.asp):

> Rule 10b5-1 is established by the Securities Exchange Commission (SEC) to
>     allow insiders of publicly traded corporations to set up a trading plan for
>     selling stocks they own. Rule 10b5-1 allows major holders to sell a
>     predetermined number of shares at a predetermined time. Many corporate
>     executives use 10b5-1 plans to avoid accusations of insider trading.

---

See also:

- [What constitutes illegal insider
  trading](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/32244/2155)
- [What is insider trading
  exactly?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/55405/2155)

Comment: Yeah but is  Rule 10b5-1  mandatory?